# How to enable CSRF for all request in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

As spring disables CSRF token for certain methods like GET, how we can enable CSRF token validation for all requests including GET using spring security.

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

Note this configuration means csrf token is required for any request ,that's unnecessary and hard to achieve